# Ratchet web socket is not working on aws ubuntu 14.04 ec2 instance

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, ratchet

I have to implement Ratchet Web Socket server on AWS Ubuntu LTS 14.04 EC2 instance so I can create chat application using php.

But my application is not connecting to Ratchet server. My php application is working fine locally well so there are no code issue. My question is :
is firewall blocking my php application to connect with AWS server?

My findings: 
Ratchet Service is running fine on AWS. Here is screenshot of 
[Ratchet Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIRPd.jpg) status.
I am not using AWB load balencer.

I also set security group from AWS Console.
Here is screen shot of security group setting:
[Security Group Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcAgl.png)

So how can I implement Ratchet with AWS EC2 Ubuntu with php application?
So where I missed any configuration?

Thanks in Advance.